# Can you prevent a WPF style from being overriden via code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We currently have the situation where we have WPF styles from a partner which we can override to customize.

However in one case it seems that the style is later being overridden by the code to which we have no access. This means that any changes I apply to the style won't have an effect because at some later point the code will come in and change it again.

The question is: Is there any way I can mark a style as not-overridable (so to speak), so no matter what happens in the code, some property values will stay the same?

Comment: I dont think its possible... Don't forget that XAML phrases to code at run-time.

Comment: I agree. I also don't think it's possible, but as always it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: I think the only way (coding involved) is to have some kind of OnStyleChanged Event handler, and cancel the change from there. And if you do get an event handler of such, you can further build a DependencyProperty to just mark it in the XAML

Comment: Does the style they did in code make sense?  Did you just ask them not to override in code?

Comment: @Blam we developers tend to forget that we can also talk to other human beings :P

Comment: @Blam, the code is coming from a development team from another software company. We can ask them (nicely) to change stuff, but in this case it's not very likely that they will agree to change their code because of this issue. This is why I wanted to check whether there is a way to fix this without having to bother them.

Comment: It looks as a by-design feature: the company yields you to create/override the default styles, but you can't override a section. Perhaps they don't want you do that. Anyway, for doing that they have to write explicitly something to prevent the override: it doesn't come "for free".

Comment: @MarioVernari It's not so much that they explicitly don't want us to override the code, it's more that they do their own development and sometimes it clashes with what we want to do. Asking them to change stuff to accomodate our needs ususally works fine, but it means having to wait for the next release (at least), so we're trying to do as much as we can on our side.

Answer (score 0):

May be it should be a comment, but I don't have permission to write comments yet.

If you created the style in code then did you explore the Style.Seal() method to set the Style.IsSealed property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.issealed.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.seal.aspx

Comment: I'm guessing we could have used this as a workaround. We now found a different solution which enables us to achieve the result we wanted, although it is a hack. We will hopefully get access to some StyleChanged event in the next release and be able to clean up the code then.